# Storing XML location in declared bean's field

Tags: java, xml, spring

Is it possible (and how) to track back location in XML file where the beans are declared?

I want to store this information in bean's field, for example, `spring/forms/login-form.xml:30:20`.

Is there easier way to do this than declaring new namespace and using **NamespaceHandler**?

**Example**
I have class `MyBean`...

```
pubic class MyBean implements SourceLocationAware {
    private String locationString;

    @Override
    public void setLocationString(String locationString){ 
        this.locationString = locationString;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLocationString(){
        return this.locationString;
    }

    /* some other delcarations */
}
```

... instance of which I want to declare in xml app context `path/to/context/my-context.xml`:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="k.p.MyBean">
   <!-- declarations -->
</bean>
```

Given those, I want `myBean` instance to have `locationString` be set as, for example, `path/to/context/my-context.xml:32:4`

Comment: can you provide a more detailed example?

Comment: @Zarathustra I've added an example in question body